# Appendix numbering and includepdf

Tags: numbering, appendices, pdfpages

```
\documentclass[a4paper, english, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[title,titletoc,toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{} 

% Endre på kapittelteksten
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter.}{0.7em}{} 
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-20pt}{0pt}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} 
\lhead{Left Head}
\rhead{Project}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}
\setlength{\headheight}{23pt} 

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{} 
    \lhead{Left Head}
    \rhead{Project}
    \rfoot{Page \thepage}
}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter


\newpage
\begin{appendices}
\pretocmd{\chapter}{
  \pagenumbering{arabic}
  \renewcommand*{\thepage}{\thechapter\arabic{page}}
}{}{}

\chapter{Something here 1}
\lipsum[1-3]

\chapter{Something here 2}
\lipsum[1-3]

\includepdf[pagecommand={\chapter{Something here 3}\section{Part 1}}, offset=0cm -5cm]{pdf1}
\includepdf[pagecommand={\section{Part 2}}, offset=0cm -5cm]{pdf1}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Problem I'm having is that appendices under "A" is numbered A1, A2, A3 and so on, but the once included with includepdf and the pagecommand to define chapters only gets numbered 1, 2, 3 etc. and not B1, B2, B3...

How to solve this?
pdf is a regular a4 page, you can use this for testing purposes: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kmfngjx0oiart7s/pdf1.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Well, you should really complete your example and give a link to the `pdf1` files

Comment: I'm not sure what happens inside includepdf but surely theres a \newpage command before the inclusion-part. If I put \chapter{Appendix A} before includepdf instead of inside the pagecommand the numbering works, but the pdf appear on a new page.

Comment: Please add a full working MWE http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that with preamble ... . pdf1 and pdf2 are only pdf pages nothing else, right?

Comment: Sorry, updated first post. pdf1 is regular a4 pdf pages. Use the one in first post.

Comment: I think you should define a pagestyle named `appendix` in which explicitly `\rfoot{Page \thechapter\arabic{page}}` is used, then say `\pagestyle{appendix}` right before the first `\includepdf` command

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use an `appendix` pagestyle explicitly in the `pagecommand` option of `\includepdf`.

The pagenumbering is reset each time when `\chapter` is used within the `appendices` environment.

Of course the scaling etc. depends on the input size of the `.pdf` file; the margin settings should be changed with `geometry`. I leave the detailed settings to the O.P, however.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, english, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[title,titletoc,toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{} 
}

\usepackage{pdfpages}



\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} 
\lhead{Left Head}
\rhead{Project}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}
\setlength{\headheight}{23pt} 

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{} 
  \lhead{Left Head}
  \rhead{Project}
  \rfoot{Page \thepage}
}

\fancypagestyle{appendix}{
  \fancyhf{} 
  \lhead{Left Head}
  \rhead{Project}
  \rfoot{Page \thechapter\arabic{page}}
}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter


\newpage
\begin{appendices}
  \pretocmd{\chapter}{%
    \clearpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \renewcommand*{\thepage}{\thechapter\arabic{page}}
  }{}{}

\chapter{Something here 1}
\blindtext[4]

\chapter{Something here 2}
\blindtext[4]

\pagestyle{appendix}
\includepdf[pagecommand={\chapter{Something here 3}\pagestyle{appendix}}, scale=0.8,offset=0cm -8cm]{pdf1}
\includepdf[pages=1,pagecommand={\section{Part 2}\pagestyle{appendix}},offset=0cm -6cm]{pdf1}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]